# update all the selected items

Tags: php, sql

I want to update all the selected items in sql.

For example, in a table I have a lot of item, all of them with a name. I want to update all this items where the name is 'aaa' for example.

Anybody knows how to do that easy?

Thanks
Best regards

Comment: Read up on `UPDATE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html and http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-data.aspx

Comment: Yes, but it update just 1 item, the first item

Comment: Place this "update multiple rows sql" in Google. One of many found http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/ - Now it's up to you to further your research.

Comment: `UPDATE farm set title='mooo' WHERE type='cow' ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depend upon how you want to handle update.

e.g,

```
1. Update all records where FIELD_NAME equal to aaa
UPDATE TABLE_NAME WHERE FIELD_NAME = 'aaa';

2. Update all records where FIELD_NAME is matched with aaa
UPDATE TABLE_NAME WHERE FIELD_NAME LIKE '%aaa%';

3. Update all records where FIELD_NAME is matched and start with aaa
UPDATE TABLE_NAME WHERE FIELD_NAME LIKE 'aaa%';

4. Update all records where FIELD_NAME is matched and end with aaa
UPDATE TABLE_NAME WHERE FIELD_NAME LIKE '%aaa';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use UPDATE clause to update records with Where clause to update only selected records

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

```
UPDATE tblName
SET columnname = newValue
WHERE name = 'aaa'
```